# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'LAST1, FIRST1' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a TSQL query that is doing 3-4 different things (my 1st attempt at this type of query).  I encounter this error on the first record:

Error: "*Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'LAST1, FIRST1' to data type int*."

The value referenced in the error is a concatenation of first and last name from a view.
**From reading other posts I have deduced that the comma is the issue but how do I get around it? Do I use substring to strip the comma out from the view before I use it or do I re-write the view or is there a CAST or parse function I can use?**

Here's overview of what the query should do:

1. Select and loop through records in a view
2. If column, "daysUntil" (int) = 30, INSERT new record into another database via stored procedure
3. Return scope_identity to output parameter @PK_ID to use in email body
4. Send email using new @PK_ID in body of email

BTW I already have a C# console app that can handle all of the above but I want to move this functionality to SQL Server.
Here's the SQL:

```
 DECLARE @MailTo varchar (1024)
 DECLARE @MailBody varchar (1024)
 DECLARE @MailSubject varchar (1024)
 DECLARE @MailFlag int

 DECLARE @Bcc varchar (256)
 SET @Bcc = 'user1@companydomain.org;user2@companydomain.org 


DECLARE @MailFrom varchar (256)
SET @MailFrom = 'recordsystem@companydomain.org'

DECLARE @Notification30Body varchar (512)
DECLARE @Notification30Subject varchar (512)

DECLARE @NotificationAllBody varchar (512)
SET @NotificationAllBody = 'REQUIREMENTS: requirements here'  

--Declare variables to hold the data which we get after looping each record
 DECLARE 
 @iEmpName VARCHAR(102),
 @iEmpID INT, 
 @iEmail1 VARCHAR(24), 
 @iRvwDate smalldatetime, 
 @idaysUntil INT 


DECLARE Empid_cur CURSOR FOR
select  EmpName, EmpID, RvwDate, Email1, daysUntil from ABC.dbo.vwEmpDataTEST  

--Flag the start of loop/curser
SET @MailFlag = 0 

OPEN Empid_cur

FETCH NEXT FROM Empid_cur 
INTO @iEmpID, @iEmpID, @RvwDate, @iEmail1, @idaysUntil

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

    IF (@idaysUntil = 30)   
        BEGIN
        DECLARE @PK_ID INT;
        EXEC XYZ.dbo.InsertEmpDataTEST @iEmpID, @PK_ID OUTPUT
        SELECT @PK_ID

        --send 30 day email here
        SET @MailTo = @iEmail1
        SET @MailBody = @Notification30Body
        SET @MailSubject = @Notification30Subject
        SET @Notification30Body = 'This Record is for ' +  @iEmpName + ' is due in 30 days. Please open the fake URL to the new Record for ' +  @iEmpName + ':' + CHAR(10) + ' http://server/Record/template.aspx?ID=' + @PK_ID  
        SET @Notification30Subject = 'Record for ' +  @iEmpName  
        SET @MailFlag = 1 --email ready
        END

        IF (@MailFlag = 1)
        BEGIN
        --send email
            EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name ='MailUser', 
            @recipients = @MailTo,
            @blind_copy_recipients = @Bcc,
            @subject = @MailSubject,
            @body = @MailBody
        END 

FETCH NEXT FROM Empid_cur 
INTO @iEmpID, @iEmpID, @RvwDate, @iEmail1, @idaysUntil
END

CLOSE Empid_cur 
DEALLOCATE Empid_cur
```

Comment: At which line you are getting error in the code? What error you are getting in the code?

Comment: The comma is not the issue, even without the comma you have a string that is being illegally treated an int somewhere in the code ...

Comment: @Chetan:Based on the value in the error, it's the first column in the first record where the error is happening.  The SQL error code is'Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 56.

Comment: @Alex - then is my code written wrong for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah, typo: You have `INTO @iEmpID, @iEmpID, ...` with the int variable repeated twice, change to `INTO @iEmpName, @iEmpID,  ...`

Comment: Thank you Alex. I had actually JUST discovered this myself and was about to post an update. Please submit as answer and I'll approve it. (The email part of my query is not sending...but I will repost a new question if I can't figure it out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `INTO @iEmpID, @iEmpID, ...` with the int variable repeated twice, change to `INTO @iEmpName, @iEmpID,...` so the columns and variables (and their types) are all aligned.